# Google sheets custom number format, color specification

Tags: google-sheets

I have a customized number format for my percentages. Here is the code:

`[Green]#,##0.0%;[Red](#,##0.0%)`

Output preview:

```
Positive:   123,456.0% # Green
Negative:   (123,456.0%) # Red
```

I want the Green to be darker, I've tried `[Dark Green]`, `[Dark_Green]`, `[dark green 1]` (from Google's fill color drop down), and even hex codes `[#00ff00]` for Green, none of them work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Color10]#,##0.0%;[Red](#,##0.0%)
```

For more information goto https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1

Comment: Thanks for Color10 for dark green! Going with `[Color10]▲#,##0%;[red]▼#,##0%`

Comment: Color docs: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions and the color palette here: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm