# How can I change custom number formatting colors using Hex?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change the colours for custom number formatting - "% change".
This is an example of a spreadsheet using standard colours.

[image: SpreadsheetView]

---

This is the standard Custom Number format screen:

[image]

---

I was wondering if there is a way to change to intensity of [green] and [red] colours and Google Sheet to make the arrows appear less striking to the eyes..

came across this thread while searching for ideas - [Google sheets custom number format, color specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153905/google-sheets-custom-number-format-color-specification)

Below is my formatting formula - is there a way for me to change the intensity of the formatted colors?

[image]

Comment: _make the arrows appear less striking to the eyes_  I'm not sure what this means - what arrows are you talking about? In any event, Google enables changes to colours in many areas but they are typically based on hex values - perhaps you should use an external tool to factor in "intensity", and then update the template with your chosen hex colours.

Comment: @Tedinoz I tried to use hex colour in the number formatting but only [green], [red] is allowed, it doesn't read hex code..

Comment: @Tedinoz https://www.ryanpraski.com/excel-google-sheets-for-digital-analytics-tips-tricks-format-percent-change-red-green/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*From the `Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format` menu item, you can specify the colours you wish to use for your number formats as one of a [specific set of 56 colours](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#chart).*

#### Example:

For example, you can use the following code:

```
[Color10]⮝ 0%;[Color30]⮟ 0%
```

To change the tone of the green and red colours. [This is the green](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23008000) and [this is the red](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23800000).

Here's an example of how it looks:

[image]

#### References:

- [Color Palette and the 56 Excel ColorIndex Colors](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#chart)
- [Format numbers in a Spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1)
- [Google Sheets API v4 - Date and Number formats - Meta Instructions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions)
- [#008000 - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23008000)
- [#800000 - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23800000)

Comment: "[Color10]▲ 0.00%;[Red]▼ -0.00%" - When applied to the arrow in a % change format, the green in `color10` DOES provides an easy-on-the-eye shade.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz, I forgot to use the custom format, edited answer.